# Search and delete from linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm having difficulties with this function.
The function is supposed to search a student in a linked list and delete this node or print an error message if the student wasn't found. The following code does not work properly, it deletes the next node after the node which is being searched for.

```
void vymazstudenta(STUDENT **head,const char *priezvisko)
{
    STUDENT *traverse = *head;
    while(traverse!=NULL)
    {
        if(!strcmp(traverse->priezvisko,priezvisko))
        {
        STUDENT *hladany = traverse->next;
        traverse->next = hladany->next;
        free(hladany);
        return;
        }
        traverse = traverse->next;
    }
        fprintf(stderr,"Student %s sa nenasiel.\n",priezvisko);
        return;
}
```

Comment: So this is what this code is doing. You need to fix it. Hint: Save the previously scanned node.

Comment: You say it in your question, it deletes the next node. You're saving a reference to the next node, then freeing it: `STUDENT *hladany = traverse->next; ... free(hladany);`

Comment: And why do you have a `free()` inside the loop when there's no `malloc()`?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker it is assumed that each node is allocated elsewhere. This function just removes a node.

Comment: This becomes arguably simpler if you just exploit that pointer-to-pointer you're already provided to walk the *pointers* in the list (which, by inference, means you're also walking the nodes they point to). [See example here](https://pastebin.com/3BTKaBbM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When traversing the list you have to store the node that preceeds the one you're checking (I used the pointer named `previous` in the code snippet below).

As you find the matching node you just set `next` on the preceeding node to `next` of the current node, this way the list skips the node to be deleted.
Then you can `free()` the matching node.

Note that you should handle the special case where the node to remove is the first one (the `head`)

In the code snippet below you see this in the `if( previous == NULL )` block - it's quite self explanatory.

```
void vymazstudenta(STUDENT **head,const char *priezvisko)
{
    STUDENT *traverse = *head;
    STUDENT *previous = NULL;
    while( traverse != NULL )
    {
        if( strcmp(traverse->priezvisko,priezvisko) == 0 )
        {
            if( previous == NULL )
            {
                *head = traverse->next;
            }
            else
            {
                previous->next = traverse->next;
            }
            free( traverse );
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            previous = traverse;
            traverse = traverse->next; 
        }
    }

    fprintf(stderr,"Student %s sa nenasiel.\n",priezvisko);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Or just double purpose the `head` pointer-to-pointer provided to the function and eliminate a decent chunk of this code. [see example here](https://pastebin.com/3BTKaBbM)

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried to keep the code similar to the snippet posted by the OP to let him better understand the logic behind the solution. Your approach of course is much more elegant.

Comment: @4386427 fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of the element **before** `traverse` so that you can change the next pointer of that element to point to the element **after** `traverse`. After that you can `free(traverse)`

Further you need to handle a special case. That is when the match is on the `*head` element. In this case you must update `*head` to get a new head of list.

Something like:

```
void vymazstudenta(STUDENT **head,const char *priezvisko)
{
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        // empty list
        return;
    }

    if(!strcmp(*head->priezvisko,priezvisko))
    {
        // Special case:
        // Remove the *head element

        STUDENT *hladany = *head;  // Save a pointer to current head
        *head = *head->next;       // Update head
        free(hladany);             // Free the previous head
        return;
    }

    STUDENT *traverse = *head->next;
    STUDENT *previous = *head;

    while(traverse!=NULL)
    {
        if(!strcmp(traverse->priezvisko,priezvisko))
        {
            previous->next = traverse->next;  // Update previous to point
                                              // to element after traverse.

            free(traverse);                   // Now free traverse
            return;
        }

        previous = traverse;                  // Move previous to next element
        traverse = traverse->next;            // Move traverse to next element
    }

    fprintf(stderr,"Student %s sa nenasiel.\n",priezvisko);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is wrong at least because it ignores the case when the header satisfies the condition.

Also you should keep the node before the deleted node.

The function can look the following way

```
void vymazstudenta( STUDENT **head, const char *priezvisko )
{
    STUDENT *tmp = NULL;

    if ( *head != NULL )
    {
        if ( strcmp( head->priezvisko, priezvisko ) == 0 )
        {
            tmp = *head;
            *head = ( *head )->next;
        }
        else
        {        
            STUDENT *traverse = *head;
            while( traverse->next != NULL && strcmp( traverse->next->priezvisko, priezvisko ) != 0 )
            {
                traverse = traverse->next;
            }

            if ( traverse->next != NULL )
            {
                tmp = traverse->next;
                traverse->next = traverse->next->next;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        free( tmp );
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Student %s sa nenasiel.\n", priezvisko );
    }
}
```